# Can I trigger a version release in Youtrack from a workflow?

Tags: workflow, youtrack

I would like to create a workflow that releases the issues current version if the state is set to a specified value. Below is an example is what I am attempting to do with the `issue.Milestone.released = true` line as psuedo code.

```
rule Release Issue when state is set to fixed.

when issue.State.changed {
  if (issue.State == {Fixed}) {
    issue.Milestone.released = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. For now you can only manipulate some properties of an issue, not of other objects.